# [[a,b], [b,a], [c,d], [d,c]] etc.2nd pair deletion

Tags: python

If I have  a list such as

```py
[[a,b], [b,a], [c,d], [d,c]]
```

But with letter pair lists not adjacent, how do I iterate through the list and end up with only one of the letter pairs?

Comment: Please work on the question phrasing so it is a little more accurate and clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about order then the easiest way is to use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) and [frozensets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset):

```py
lst = [[a,b], [b,a], [c,d], [d,c]] 
result =  [list(x) for x in {frozenset(t) for t in lst}]

# result output: [[a,b], [c,d]]
```

Since `frozenset([a,b]) == frozenset([b,a])`, the set comprehension `{frozenset(t) for t in lst}` will include each pair only once. The outer list comprehension converts back the set of frozensets to a list of lists.